# expo image picker issue in android expo app

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, multer, expo-image-picker

when I try to upload .heic image using expo image picker it is getting corrupted and not showing in web and windows,

this is what i am getting when picking image from expo-image-picker
{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, "fileName": "1000000328.heic", "filesize": 1442278, "height": 3000, "mimeType": "image/heic", "rotation": null, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%252FUR-Protection-Security-ReactNative/ImagePicker/21dacf70-46e1-4933-ac1e-c0ca0140cd60.jpeg", "width": 4000}

and this is what I am sending it to node-multer server to upload image
{"name": "21dacf70-46e1-4933-ac1e-c0ca0140cd60.jpeg", "type": "image/jpg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%25FUR-Protection-Security-ReactNative/ImagePicker/21dacf70-46e1-4933-ac1e-c0ca0140cd60.jpeg"}

I am changing image type to "image/jpg" because "image/heic" is not showing either

Comment: I stopped using expo for the same reason. it has so much trouble everytime